# When I name colums i Can no longer edit cells in gridview in winforms

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net winforms to display as csv file in a grid. I import into sql a normalized table using entity framework, then retrieve  my deliveries table obj in the query below.

```
Private Sub frmConfirmDeliverys_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim bs As New BindingSource


    bs.DataSource = (From u In threeContext.dbContext.skechersDeliveries Where u.isprocessed = False Select New With {.OrderNumber = u.ordernumber, .BarCode = u.tagbarcode, .Qty = u.qty, .Location = u.location})


    bs.ResetBindings(True)
    dgDeliverys.DataSource = bs
    dgDeliverys.BeginEdit(True)
```

Comment: And you must have an error?

Comment: @ZL1Corvette no errors the values are displayed i just cant edit them

Comment: @aldux I retreieve the deliverys table obv in the query their

Comment: Sorry bud, but I still do not understand... Maybe you want to rephrase it once again.

Comment: @aldux When using the above query instead of calling select u i cant edit the columns within gridview but when I use select u i can I need to give the columns friendly names but then i cant edit the cells in the gridview its like they go readonly

Comment: Use the select U method and in the datagridview define columns, use HeaderText property to give column a friendly name e.g. HeaderText="Order No".

Comment: @Mych but when i do that the rows are not filled in

Comment: @DavidB You said that if you use Select u then the columns populate and are editable but if you user Select New With then populates but not editable. Can you post one of your column definitions with the HeaderText property set. Are you using Bind or EVal to show data?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question ? Anyway if your problem is you can't change your datagridview column header cause of the Datasource, you can replace the  column header

example:

"SELECT ID_No ***AS [ID Number]*** FROM DBStudent"

Instead of display ID_No it will display ID Number